# Windows 8 64 bit - Automatic Repair loop

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, system-restore

This is not the first time I have face this problem. Last time when I stuck in this loop I just reinstall my computer.

But right now I don't have the CD Win 8 or iso file so I find the solution from here: [Automatic Repair fails to repair my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/741965/automatic-repair-fails-to-repair-my-pc)

Since their solution doesn't work, I tried my self to accest to SrtTrail.txt throught command promt. There was only one problem listed in SrtTrail.txt:

> Root cause found:
>
> —————————
>
> Boot critical file d:\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe is corrupt.
>
> Repair action: File repair
>
> Result: Failed. Error code =  0×3
>
> Time taken = 1188 ms

So I used the HIREN BOOT disk, went to Mini windows 7 to look up to this "ntoskrnl.exe" file but I didn't find it. I think the file was missed somehow.

I looked up in the Internet but couldn't find any solution to fix this problem, especially when it's come ntoskrnl file. I know it would be simple if I just reinstall my computer, but it's so waste of time.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take ANY ntoskrnl.exe from somewhere !

ntoskrnl is the most important part of a Windows system.

I would save my user files like documents, pictures etc. and do a fresh installation.

You can [download Windows 8 with your product key from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only).

Alternatively [download Windows 8 virtual machine](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/) and extract ntoskrnl.exe from there.

Comment: Well I just installed win 8 on my computer yesterday and saved all my files by using hiren boots disk.

But the idea of using virtual machine to extract this file is amazing, I never though about that before. I really appreciated your help.

Sorry for unable to upvote you cause I didn't have enough reptuation :(